# mod_rewrite ignore specific query string param

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have the following in htaccess and it works fine

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/artist\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^bandid=([0-9]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /band.php?BandId=%1 [L]
```

but some old referes send other querystring params:

`bandid=1326&order=ASC&orderby=Tdate`

to which apache gives them `404`

how can i tell `mod_rewrite` to ignore any other params after bandid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)bandid=([0-9]*)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^artist\.php$ /band.php?BandId=%1 [L,NC]
```

Regex  `(^|&)bandid=([0-9]*)(&|$)` will make sure to match `bandid=1326` irrespective of presence of other query parameters.